# GNU assembler is not giving the proper floating point value

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler, x87

I am trying to write the following code:

```
.data
float_val: .float 0e122.23
.text
.global _start
_start:
fldl float_val
mov $60,%rax
xor %rdi,%rdi
syscall
```

After using gdb, the value in `st(0)` is some garbage. Why so? I am not understanding where the problem is. A YASM counterpart is working correctly.

Comment: Typo in the following line: `mov $60,rax` should be `%rax` or it won't build

Comment: uh yeah thanks.... it is one of biggest typo I am having after moving from yasm to gas

Comment: In future make sure you're copy/pasting the code you actually ran, so typos are impossible.  That one was easy to sort out, since you wouldn't have been able to test in GDB because it wouldn't assemble, but it still wastes people's time commenting on it.  In another case, a typo could introduce a  runtime bug and make things harder  to sort out for people answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dFloat.html#i386_002dFloat), the mnemonic suffixes are different for floating-point instructions than for integer.  Integer instructions use the `l` suffix for a 32-bit dword; but for floating-point instructions, `l` is for a 64-bit double.  You use `s` for a 32-bit single-precision float.  So write `flds float_val` and it should work.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood , thanks for clearing